# Redirect index.php to root but not subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, root

I want to redirect `www.domainname.com/index.php` to `www.domainname.com`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used this code, but it redirects `www.domainname.com/admin/index.php` as well.
However, I don't want to redirect `www.domainname.com/admin/index.php`.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why you have `\s` character in your condition?

Comment: To (doubly) make sure `index.php` is matched right after `domain.com` and not after `domain.com/admin/`

Comment: Hi,I used the same code but it doesn;t worked for me. :( Can you pls tell me why?

Comment: I need more details to track it down. You better post a new question and I will attend.